# How to find dashes in regex for searching phone numbers?

Tags: regex

I have this Regex that helps me to find a phone number in a text:

```
\+?(972|0)(\-)?0?(([23489]{1}\d{7})|[5]{1}\d{8})
```

I would like to find a phone number with a dashes, this Regex isn't working with dashes.

I tried to modified the regex to find also phone number with dases, but without any success.

How can i add the dashes to my Regex?

Comment: give the format of numbers at least..

Comment: it seems to **[work](https://regex101.com/r/pX1dU3/1)**

Comment: you can test it with for example 050-0000000 it works with 0500000000

Answer (score 0):

```
(1[\s-]?)?\(?(\d{3}\)?[-\s]?\d{3}[-\s]?\d{4}
```

This regex will match all these (and any variantion of dashes and spaces but always with the 3-3-4 (US) format):

```
1 (123) 456 7890
1234567890
123 456 7890
123-456-7890
1-123-456-7890
1-(213)-456-7890
```

The regex below is more international oriented:

```
((\+|00)\d+)?[\s-]?(\(\d\))?[\d-\s]+
```

It will match these:

```
+31612345678
+31 (0)6 1234 5678
0031 (0)30 12345678
+313012345678
030-1234567
0612345678
070 1234567
```

But also:

```
123456789123456789123456789
```

I hope this helps you further with your question